# Javascript can't locate HTML form ID

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a basic HTML form, and a Javascript form validator that looks for any input value in the "first name" field. The problem I'm having is that nothing seems to be working to return the first name form value to check it in JS.

Relevant HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="formName">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="fn" >
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="ln" >
    <br>
    Email address: <span style="color:red">(required)</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" >
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

My JS:

```
var validate = function (){
    var x = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    if (x == null || "" || "undefined"){
        alert("Please fill out your first name");
        return false;
    }
    kickoff();
}

var kickoff = function () {
    var visitor = document.forms["form1"].fn.value;
    alert("Thanks for filling out, " + visitor +"\n");
    return visitor;
};
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frg37t3u/).

My X variable is never reached, it seems, and keeps returning "undefined" when I submit the page. I've been fiddling with it for quite a while and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: This syntax `if (x == null || "" || "undefined"){` is incorrect.

Comment: Besides all of the syntax issues, that method is also out-of-scope. You can either in-line the script higher up in the DOM or define `validate` directly on the `window` object (`window.validate = func...`).
Neither case is ideal, you should know.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't mean what you think:

```
if (x == null || "" || "undefined") {
```

Can also be written as:

```
if ((x == null) ||    // might be false
    ""          ||    // will be false
    "undefined"       // will be true
   ) {
```

so the `if` will *always* be true.

You really just need:

```
if (! x) {
```

Comment: P.S: (!x) will validate `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax issues, that method is also out-of-scope. You're not even going to be able to debug the issue with your conditional until you fix that.

You can either in-line the script higher up in the DOM or define `validate` directly on the `window` object:

```
window.validate = function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frg37t3u/5/

Neither case is ideal, you should know. Globals are bad, but that's another discussion.